# Review: Built-In Functions

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is a two-parter: first, define a function, distance_from_zero, with one parameter (choose any parameter name you like).

Second, have that function do the following:

Check the type of the input it receives.
If the type is int or float, the function should return the absolute value of the function input.
If the type is any other type, the function should return "Not an integer or float!"

code:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
print type(n)
if type(n) == int or type(n) == float:
    var = abs(n)
    print var
    return n
else:
    print "no!"
    return n

var = input("Enter number:")
print var
distance_from_zero(var)
```

Comment: doenot work for strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as the others have suggested, use `raw_input()`.

Then, you can try to convert it to an `int` or `float`. If both of those fail, you don't have a number. If you want to keep the "original" type, you can use this:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            n = float(n)
        except ValueError:
            print "Not a number!"
            n = float("NaN")
    return abs(n)
```

If you don't mind if the input `1` is converted to `1.0`, then you can simplify the function:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    try:
        return abs(float(n))
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a number!"
        return float("NaN")  # or remove this line to return None
```

In both cases, you would call the function like this:

```
var = raw_input("Enter number: ")
print distance_from_zero(var)
```

Comment: But isn't this somewhat difficult for starters?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

`input()` in Python 2.7 is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. So if you input "hello", it will raise a `NameError` (unless there is a variable hello). If you're working with Python 2.7, use `raw_input()`. However, if you are using python 3, then use `input()`, because `raw_input()` does not exist in Python 3 (and input is the exact same as raw_input in 3)

You also returned n and not `var`, the absolute value.

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    try:
        return abs(float(n))
    except ValueError:
        return "That is not an integer or float!"

var = raw_input("Enter number:")
print var
distance_from_zero(var)
```

Also, for checking types, you should be using [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: the problem is..if it is string it gives error in the beginning

Comment: @dummy Yep, I have edited my answer to explain that (at the top)

Comment: i replaced my function with yours but no luck

Comment: @dummy No, use `raw_input()` to get input instead of `input()`

Comment: i want to try with both...numeric/float and string so if some one enter non numeric/non float it should give print error message...

Comment: @dummy okay, the function now prints if it is a string

Comment: no....even though i am importing import ast....it gives me error NameError: global name 'isinstace' is not defined

Comment: @dummy Sorry! Typo in my answer! It should be `isinstance`

Comment: But this doesn't work! `n` is a string, so `isinstance(n, float)` will always be `False`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker That's where the try/except comes in when it tried to do `int(string)`

Comment: @TimPietzcker then what it should be?

Comment: @dummy: I've written an answer. Haidro, what do you get for the input "1.5"?

Comment: I must say I still don't like it. The `isinstance()` check is superfluous, isn't it? `raw_input()` will always return a `str`. Also, the error message is misleading ("is not a number") would be better, you're not checking for integers at all (that may or may not be necessary. Probably not).

Answer (score 1):

Here your code has some flaws. When you get a user input through `input()`, it throws error for any non numeric input. use `raw_input()`. To check the type of the input received, use `literal_eval()`

```
import ast
def distance_from_zero(n):
    try:        
         x = ast.literal_eval(n)
         if isinstance(x, (int,float)):
             var = abs(x)
             print type(var)
             return var
    except:
         print "No!"
```

Comment: @Dummy: thats what i have used `literal_eval()` for. Raw input accepts both numeric and non numeric input.

Comment: @Dummy: What does that mean?

Comment: print var
    return n
else:
    print "no!"
    return n
import ast
def distance_from_zero(n):
    x=ast.literal_eval(n)
    if isinstance(x,(int,float)):
        var=abs(x)
print var
    return n
else:
    print "no!"
    return n

var = input("Enter number:")
print var
distance_from_zero(var)

Comment: the same code. Instead of `input()` , use `raw_input("Enter Number")`

Comment: Haidro's answer works fine...but thank you for the help Aswin

Comment: `literal_eval()` fails on strings that aren't a literal. Try `distance_from_zero("hello") to see what I mean.

Comment: Now it's syntactically incorrect and still doesn't work. It doesn't return anything, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    if type(n) is int or type (n) is float:
       return abs(n)
       #return  abs(n)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```

Comment: Please provide explanation for your answer